# Как закрасить границу объединённой ячейки через Google App Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

В столбце "A" перечислены запчасти авто, многие из строк объединены между собой (только в столбе "A"). После каждой запчасти идёт граница во всю строку. Раньше делал их в ручную, сегодня решил исправить это с помощью скрипта.

Расскажу о скрипте, как работает:
Поскольку я заранее не могу знать о всех дополнительных свойствах запчастей, я сначала через цикл удаляю все нижние границы, после использую данный цикл:

```
  var ranges = [];

  for(var i = 1; i < firstColumn.length; i++)
  {
    if(firstColumn[i][0])
    {
      ranges.push("A" + i + ":" + i);
    }
  }
```

Он определяет, где заканчивается объединённая ячейка и после я закрашиваю границу:

```
return sheet.getRangeList(ranges).setBorder(null, null, true, null, null, null);
```

Всё работает, как надо, но везде, где есть объединённые ячейки граница не прорисовывается.

Как это исправить?

Comment: Я сам понимаю, что вероятнее всего, что я нахожу начальную ячейку в столбце "A", из-за этого и не прорисовывается граница самой нижней (объединённой) ячейки, но как это исправить - не знаю

Comment: Дубль https://qna.habr.com/q/1124572